# How to write a db_query with condition on a datefield with enddate - value1 and value2

Tags: 7, database

Trying to do following select query on a node with datefield with endvalue:

```
  SELECT nid FROM {node}
  WHERE uid = $uid
  AND type = $type
  AND field_mytime(value) > $daystart
  AND field_mytime(value2) < $dayend;


  db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node}
     WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type AND field_mytime['und'][0]['value'] > :value, field_time['und'] [0]['value2'] < :value2',
    array(':uid' => $u, ':type' => 'mycontenttype', ':value' => $daystart, ':value2' => $dayend))->fetchField();
```

This do not work of cource: 
  field_mytime['und'][0]['value']
  field_mytime['und'][0]['value2']

But what will work? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Fields are not stored in the node/entity table to which they relate, it would be quite inefficient to do that.

Drupal 7 introduced the new [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class to help you build up these kinds of queries. I'd recommend reading the docs, but for your purposes the code would look something like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', $type)
  ->propertyCondition('uid', $uid)
  ->fieldCondition('field_mytime', 'value', $daystart, '>')
  ->fieldCondition('field_mytime', 'value2', $dayend, '<');

$results = $query->execute();
if (isset($results['node'])) {
  // Load all node objects based on the results of the query
  $nids = array_keys($results['node']);
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Clive, very nice, solved my problem. But if ($isset($results['node'])) {
must be: if (isset($results['node'])) {

Comment: @cord1 So it should, sorry about that :)